# download partial by using GetFileById sharepoint REST-API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, download

I want to download only a part of a file using the 'GetFileById' SharePoint REST api but I don't not see any references in the documentation about support for partial file download.

I tried using HTTP 'Range' header (Adding to the HTTP headers the following header:  `'Range': 'bytes=0-1023'`), but it still downloaded the entire file. Also, when I received the file, I did not see 'Accept-Ranges' as part of the server's answer, which also makes me believe it is not supported.

Does someone know if this feature is supported and in this case how it can be implemented?

If it makes any difference for the answer, I am using SharePoint Online.

Comment: Update:
I received an official answer, it is not supported (for now..)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same, until I eventually discovered that only SharePoint online STILL does not support this option, see this newer reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/caching-and-performance-planning

Too bad it would be a nice feature to have